# How to use Github?

Tags: github

I have created a GitHub account.

I'd like to know how to use it and why is should be used.

Comment: http://support.github.com/ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub hosts git repositories. Git is a Distributed Revision Control System which allows you to store source code (or other data) in a versioned repository, and then (if you so desire) share that information and collaborate with other people.

A good free book to get started with using Git is ProGit ( http://progit.org/book/ )

GitHub hosts Git repositories in such a way that it combines a social networking type site with a programming site to create a social programming site. You can just push your git repos up to GitHub to share your code with the world.

Comment: How i will upload my souce file there on to git hub

Comment: @Rahul Mehta Last time I checked a short guide explaining this was displayed after creating a repo on github.

Comment: @Rahul: See this page ( http://help.github.com/ ) and do the "Getting Started with Git and GitHub" walkthrough and it will give you a good idea of the process. Specifically, this page ( http://help.github.com/creating-a-repo/ ) should tell you how to set up a repo and push code to it. (Though you will need to set up your SSH keypair as is described on the help site).

Answer (score 2):

http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1

I was just viewing a git hub tutorial today!  Git Hub on code school.  You may have to sign up for a free account.  I stopped about halfway through because its going to be awhile before I need git hub, but I feel like I learned some stuff.

Are you using a mac?  There is a git hub app.  http://mac.github.com/  I can't say anything about it though.